# How to update environment variable key name dynamically using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm reading the environment variables (Key & Value) dynamically and forming below array:

```
commands: [
    {
        name: 'PRODUCT_NAME',
        value: 'iPhone'
    },
    {
        name: 'PRODUCT_PRICE',
        value: '1232'
    },
    {
        name: 'PRODUCT_TYPE',
        value: 'Electronics'
    },
    {
        name: 'PRODUCT_ID',
        value: 'SKU29389438'
    },
    {
        name: 'LOG_ENABLED',
        value: 'TRUE'
    },    
]
```

I want to update the **`key`** name for these two properties dynamically **`PRODUCT_TYPE`** `->` `myapp.property.type.event` **and** **`PRODUCT_ID`** `->` `myapp.property.product.enabled`

**Final output should look like this:**

```
commands: [
    {
        name: 'PRODUCT_NAME',
        value: 'iPhone'
    },
    {
        name: 'PRODUCT_PRICE',
        value: '1232'
    },
    {
        name: 'myapp.property.type.event',
        value: 'Electronics'
    },
    {
        name: 'myapp.property.product.enabled',
        value: 'SKU29389438'
    },
    {
        name: 'LOG_ENABLED',
        value: 'TRUE'
    },    
]
```

Please find my **`product.js`** code below:

```
const commands = (Object.entries(process.env).map(([key, value]) => ({ name: key, value })))
console.log("commands : ", commands);
```

I'm new to Nodejs, can someone please help how can I update these two key dynamically and form the final array?

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** You can just loop over and change the `name` as:

```js
const obj = {
  commands: [
    {
      name: "PRODUCT_NAME",
      value: "iPhone",
    },
    {
      name: "PRODUCT_PRICE",
      value: "1232",
    },
    {
      name: "PRODUCT_TYPE",
      value: "Electronics",
    },
    {
      name: "PRODUCT_ID",
      value: "SKU29389438",
    },
    {
      name: "LOG_ENABLED",
      value: "TRUE",
    },
  ],
};

obj.commands.forEach((o) => {
  if (o.name === "PRODUCT_TYPE") o.name = "myapp.property.type.event";
  if (o.name === "PRODUCT_ID") o.name = "myapp.property.product.enabled";
});

console.log(obj.commands);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output full height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**2)** You can also do as :

**`one-liner`**

```
obj.commands.forEach((o) => (o.name = changes[o.name] ?? o.name));
```

```js
const obj = {
  commands: [{
      name: "PRODUCT_NAME",
      value: "iPhone",
    },
    {
      name: "PRODUCT_PRICE",
      value: "1232",
    },
    {
      name: "PRODUCT_TYPE",
      value: "Electronics",
    },
    {
      name: "PRODUCT_ID",
      value: "SKU29389438",
    },
    {
      name: "LOG_ENABLED",
      value: "TRUE",
    },
  ],
};
const changes = {
  PRODUCT_TYPE: "myapp.property.type.event",
  PRODUCT_ID: "myapp.property.product.enabled",
};

obj.commands.forEach((o) => {
  if (changes[o.name]) o.name = changes[o.name];
});

console.log(obj.commands);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output full height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you @decpk. Is there any option to exclude certain keys for example I want to exclude this key LOG_ENABLED, how can we achieve this?

Comment: then don't include it in the `changes` object.